# Find perfect squares

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to write a loop that calls a method to determine if a number entered is a perfect square. It compiles just fine so I must have a logic error, for the life of me though I can't find it. No matter the number I put in it seems to always return false, leading me to believe the problem lies inside the isPerfect() method. I however, do not know enough about java yet to know where to go from here. Here's the code I've got so far:

```
 public class Square
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         int input = 0; //The default value for input
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         while (input != -1)
         {
             System.out.println("Please enter a number, or enter -1 to quit");
             input = keyboard.nextInt();
             if (isPerfect(input) == true) //Call isPerfect() to determine if is a perfect square
             {
                 System.out.println(input + " is a perfect square.");
             }
             else if(input == -1) //If equals exit code, quit
             {
                 break;
             }
             else //If it is not a perfect square... it's not a perfect square
             {
                 System.out.println(input + " is not a perfect square.");
             }
         }
     }




     public static boolean isPerfect(int input)
     {      
         double num = Math.sqrt(input); //Take the square root of the number passed

         if (((num * num) == input) && (num%1 == 1)) //If the number passed = it's roots AND has no remainder, it must be a perfect sqaure
         {
             return true; //Return true to the call
         }
         else
         {
             return false; //Return false to the call
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two potential issues.

1. arithmetic with doubles is inaccurate. You probably want

   ```
   int num = Math.round(Math.sqrt(input));
   ```
2. Your test for no remainder doesn't do what you think ... `(num%1 == 1)` just tests whether `n` is odd. And you dont really need it .. all you need is `if( num*num == input) { ... }`

Comment: I get a conversion error when trying #1, though number two seems to have worked. Now that I see it it makes a whole lot more sense then the convoluted witchery I was attempting.
`code: 'Square.java:47: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int`              `

Comment: I fixed it, changed to 
int num = ((int)Math.sqrt(input));

Answer (score 0):

So with the program fixed, here is the entirety of the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Square
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         int input = 0; //The default value for input
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         while (input != -1)
         {
             System.out.println("Please enter a number, or enter -1 to quit");
             input = keyboard.nextInt();
             if (isPerfect(input) == true) //Call isPerfect() to determine if is a perfect square
             {
                 System.out.println(input + " is a perfect square.");
             }
             else if(input == -1) //If equals exit code, quit
             {
                 System.out.println("Breaking!");
                 break;
             }
             else //If it is not a perfect square... it's not a perfect square
             {
                 System.out.println(input + " is not a perfect square.");
             }

         }
     System.out.println("Main complete!");
     }


    /**
        The isPerfect() method returns whether or not a number is a perfect square.
        @param input The input from the keyboard scanner, passed as an argument
    */

     public static boolean isPerfect(int input)
     {      
         int num = ((int)Math.sqrt(input)); //Take the square root of the number passed, as an integer

         if (num*num == input) //If the number passed = it's roots AND has no remainder, it must be a perfect sqaure
         {
             return true; //Return true to the call
         }
         else
         {
             return false; //Return false to the call
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class perfect
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int count=0;
        System.out.println ("enter any number");
        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=in.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(n>i*i)
            {
               count++;
               System.out.println( i*i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("there are "+ count + " perfect numbers");
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain why this code is correct?

Comment: For future reference... this was asked Oct 26 '15 at 2:53. In the future I would suggest perhaps finding more recent posts? As well this problem was already solved. Thank you for your time, but as I just stated, the problem was solved over 3 years ago.